# Why httpclient sent an unknown parent span id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, trace

I implemented 2 .net 6 webapi. Let's call it api-A and api-B.

api-A uses httpclient to call api-B.

```
_logger.LogInformation($"CallHealthcheckEndpoint : " +
    $"Actvity Id =>{Activity.Current?.Id}, " +
    $"Parent Id =>{Activity.Current?.ParentId}, " +
    $"Trace id => {Activity.Current?.TraceId}, " +
    $"Span id => {Activity.Current?.SpanId}");
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(path);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    await HttpResponseProcessor.ProcessFailedResponse(response);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

What I expect is the traceparent header is set properly

Actual result:

api-A:

```
Activity.Current?.Id    "00-6e6a9de46981ec50f199ddde7f1bfadb-ada07e3b7c1ff9ec-00"
```

The request header from httpclient is

```
{traceparent: 00-6e6a9de46981ec50f199ddde7f1bfadb-dba3cb135b3e6af2-00}
```

As you can see, the highlighted parts don't match (ada07e3b7c1ff9ec vs dba3cb135b3e6af2)